# Python selenium webdriver get stack

Tags: python, selenium

I implemented below code to check selenium, but it get stuck, firefox window is not opened and nothing of error appears. print line is not executed.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get("http://www.python.org")
 print 'aaa'
 driver.close()
```

I using 2.7.0 Selenium version and 44.0.2 firefox version. any idea what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your *selenium is too old* for the firefox 44, **upgrade**:

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```